# One composite index or two separate indices

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization

I have three tables `A`, `B` and `C` that must be joined.

- The columns in A are `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`.
- Columns in B include `b1, b2, b3, b4` and `b5`.
- The columns in C are `c1`, `c2` and `c3`.

The query is going to be

```
SELECT B.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON a1 = b1 and a2 = b2
INNER JOIN C ON b3 = c1
WHERE <some conditions>
```

Should I make a composite index using the values b1, b2, and b3 or two indices with idx1 = (b1, b2), and idx2 = (b3)? Of course, table A has an index that contains (a1, a2), and table C has an index on (c1).

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Delete the unrelated tag.)

Comment: Show us table definitions, incl. primary and foreign keys, and unique constraints.

Comment: In both Oracle and MS SQL server

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags for .ow; you'll need to (re)add the appropriate tag(s).

Comment: The two product can behave very differently, @yxw158 . Focus this question on one of them and then if you have questions on the other afterwards then post a *new* question(s) asking any other questions you have about that one.

Comment: OK, thanks. Let's do it for Oracle for now

Comment: Is joining these three tables your only use case? There is never a circumstance in which you need to join tables `B` and `C` without `A`?

Comment: In my situation, table A and B are always needed to join, not table C.

Comment: Separate. b3 won't be useful by itself in an index, if it's in third place.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your data volume and the nature of how you will be querying the table. In many situations (a report against a significant portion of your table's rows) it's better to not use indexes at all. Even if indexes are appropriate, you are using inner joins - if your WHERE clause has predicates that makes Oracle decide to start with table B or C instead of A, that totally changes your indexing requirements. That's why nobody can answer your question without knowing a lot more about your query plans and data volumes.

But assuming indexes are appropriate because you're going after only a tiny percentage of your data, and assuming your predicate will get Oracle to start with table A every time (big assumptions here), you'll get the best query performance out of concatenated indexes on the tables you are joining to that line up with your predicates. So, you may want to index:

```
B(b1,b2) -- single, two-column index, to satisfy your join to B
C(c1)    -- single, one-column index, to satisfy your join to C.
```

Comment: Thanks. So no need to have B(b3)? b3 joins with c1

Comment: Not if the join order is A->B->C... you will only use an index on the table two which you are joining, not from which you are joining. But as I said in my answer, because these are inner joins Oracle is free to reverse your join order. Then you actually might need b3 indexed.